# How to override FOR IN loop list behavior?

Tags: python, list, overriding

I try to implement list which returns wrapped elements when accessing directly (by index) or via FOR IN loop statement. At present I have following code:

```
class ItemWrappedList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, y):
        result = super().__getitem__(y)
        return f'<item>{result}</item>'


lst = ItemWrappedList(['1', '2', '3'])

for pos in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[pos])

#>>> <item>1</item>
#>>> <item>2</item>
#>>> <item>3</item>

for value in lst:
    print(value)
#>>> 1
#>>> 2
#>>> 3
```

As you can see first loop works correctly, as intended. But second loop calls list methods that I was unable to override. Are there any possibilities to force ItemWrappedList class to have same behavior in all situations?

P.S. I tried different ways with implementing/overriding `__next__` and `__iter__` methods, but seems that `__next__` ever not called.

Comment: An `__iter__` method is indeed the way to control this. Presumably whatever you tried with that was not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the `__iter__` method should do the trick:

```
class ItemWrappedList(list):

    def __getitem__(self, y):
        result = super().__getitem__(y)
        return f'<item>{result}</item>'

    def __iter__(self):
        return (f'<item>{x}</item>' for x in list.__iter__(self))


lst = ItemWrappedList(['1', '2', '3'])

for pos in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[pos])


for value in lst:
    print(value)
```

```
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
<item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
<item>3</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was that I was trying to override the "next" method which was not being called.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you say `for i in lst` Python first calls `iter()` on `lst`. If `lst`'s class has implemented `__iter__` method, it is the first thing that is considered. Otherwise it proceeds to see if it has implemented `__getitem__`. (Otherwise it raises `TypeError: object is not iterable`)

Since you inherit from `list` and the `list` class already defined `__iter__`, `iter()` always finds its `__iter__` first not your `__getitem__`.

So just implement `__iter__` for your class:

```py
class ItemWrappedList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, y):
        result = super().__getitem__(y)
        return f"<item>{result}</item>"

    def __iter__(self):
        return (f"<item>{item}</item>" for item in super().__iter__())


lst = ItemWrappedList(["1", "2", "3"])

for pos in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[pos])


for value in lst:
    print(value)
```